# Using GmailAPI with GAE application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to integrate GmailAPI with a GAE Application. I have created the GAE application using Maven. The application works fine.
I am following this tutorial to integrate GmailAPI:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java
and I have used the code provided there.
However, I have a Null Pointer Exception starting at this line:
DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

```
/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/gmail-java-quickstart");
    ...
        static {
                try {
                    ...
                    DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
    ...
```

When retrieving t.getMessage() I get: `java.nio.file.Files is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details`
The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(StoredCredential.java:171)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:736)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:209)
        at com.google.appengine.demos.GmailManager.authorize(GmailManager.java:72)
        at com.google.appengine.demos.GmailManager.getGmailService(GmailManager.java:91)
        at com.google.appengine.demos.HibernateJpaServlet.doGet(HibernateJpaServlet.java:36)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:469)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     20:09:30.803 Uncaught exception from servlet
      java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(StoredCredential.java:171)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:736)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:209)
        at com.google.appengine.demos.GmailManager.authorize(GmailManager.java:72)
        at com.google.appengine.demos.GmailManager.getGmailService(GmailManager.java:91)
        at com.google.appengine.demos.HibernateJpaServlet.doGet(HibernateJpaServlet.java:36)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:469)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found this part in the documentation:

> The Filesystem
>
> A Java application cannot use any classes used to write to the
>   filesystem, such as java.io.FileWriter. An application can read its
>   own files from the filesystem using classes such as
>   java.io.FileReader. An application can also access its own files as
>   "resources", such as with Class.getResource() or
>   ServletContext.getResource().
>
> Only files that are considered "resource files" are accessible to the
>   application via the filesystem. By default, all files in the WAR are
>   "resource files." You can exclude files from this set using the
>   appengine-web.xml file. Any suggestions how I should change the code
>   in order for it to work with GAE?

How can I create the file .credentials/gmail-java-quickstart? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: that turorial is for generic java and not for appengine. look for an appengine specific tutorial which stores those files as resources or in datastore.

Comment: @ZigMandel, yep, http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/05/accessing-gmail-accounts-from-app.html should help.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Thank you for the tutorial! I will definitely have a look at it! I manged to pass that error by using: AppEngineDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY = AppEngineDataStoreFactory.getDefaultInstance();

Comment: Always glad to help, and glad that you passed that hurdle.